# Fitting images with different dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am building a webpage for homework purposes and I am struggling to fit in four photos with different dimensions in a grid layout. To be more specific I have to make that grid layout be responsive as a 4-grid layout on Desktop view, 2-grid layout on Tablet view, and Mobile view. I have tried a lot of advice from different articles but none of them seems to be working.

**CSS code:**

```
  .services{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height:100vh; 
    max-width:100%; 
    object-fit:cover;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .services{
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
```

**HTML code:**

```
     <div>
        <div class="services">
          <img src="./Photos/services-1.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
          <img src="./Photos/services-2.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
          <img src="./Photos/services-3.jpg"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="services">
          <img src="./Photos/services-4.jpg"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Current look:**

[image]

I want photos to be in a line for each occasion with certain dimensions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Using JS (on resize) - Get height of the smallest one and set it on other images? Instead of using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: this is a useful article: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for submitting your question! Instead of using  markup for placing your images, I would suggest using  with a background-image. Why? With background-image you can use 'background-size: cover' wich make the image cover the whole  with a custom height, so the columns are all equal.

Trying to achieve this with regular  tags needs a some sort of resizer or the images need to be the same width and height already.

Below my code! **Tip:** You don't have to close the  tag, you can use it without the closing image tag.

**HTML**

```
 <div>
<div class="services">
  <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');"></div>
</div>
<div class="services">
   <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');"></div>
</div>
<div class="services">
  <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');"></div>
</div>
<div class="services">
  <div class="image-box" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
     .services{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height:100vh; 
    max-width:100%; 
    object-fit:cover;
  }
  
  .services .image-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .services{
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for grid you need to define `display: grid;` in the parent `div`

```
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}
.services{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1180px) {
    .grid{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    }
}
```

in HTML , in the place of `'level'` add your image code it will work in both responsive

```
 <div class="grid">
         <div class="services">
             level
         </div>
         <div class="services">
             level
         </div>
         <div class="services">
             level
         </div>
         <div class="services">
             level
         </div>
     </div>
```

if you want the image to be cover add this in `img` class `object-fit: cover;`
This will work fine .